# Mapbox No Source With This ID

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I want to remove sources and layers on Mapbox map. I managed to remove every sources and layers except for the first source and layer that I have added to Mapbox map.

Note that I am not good in using jQuery $.post.

Here is how I add all the sources and layers.

```
$.post('ajax/marker.php', function(data)
{
    var firstSplit = data.split(",");

    for(i=0;i<firstSplit.length-1;i++)
    {
        var secondSplit = firstSplit[i].split("|");
        var id = secondSplit[0];
        var lat = secondSplit[1];
        var lng = secondSplit[2];

        var point = {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [lat, lng]
        };

        map.addSource(id, { type: 'geojson', data: point });
        map.addLayer({
            "id": id,
            "type": "symbol",
            "source": id,
            "layout": {
                "icon-image": "airport-15"
            }
        }); 
    }
});
```

**Remember that, I managed to view all the sources and layers on Mapbox map.**
Its just that I am **not able to remove only the first source and layers** that I have added to the map. I hope someone out there has some ideas regarding this problem. Thanks.

I used the two statements below in a loop to remove sources and layers.

```
map.removeSource(id);
map.removeLayer(id);
```

I did a test to remove the first source and layers manually as below but it did not work.

```
map.removeSource('1612280004A');
map.removeLayer('1612280004A');
```

However, it works on the next sources and layers.

Comment: Is the first source also used as the initial map style? If so, try adding a blank background styl, then all your other sources.

Answer (score 6):

My best guess from what you've posted is that you can't remove the layer while there are still sources attached to it. Try reversing the order of your two statements:

`map.removeLayer('1612280004A');
map.removeSource('1612280004A');`

Answer (score 3):

My GeoJson shared the same ID. Removing both layer and source fixed this issue

```js
 function RemoveMapLayer() {
        var mpLayer = map.getLayer("points");
        if (typeof mpLayer === 'undefined') {
            // No Layer
        } else {
            map.removeLayer("points");
        }

        var mpSource = map.getSource("points");
        if (typeof mpSource === 'undefined') {
            alert("no source");
        } else {
            map.removeSource("points");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before deleting, check if the source and layer are present, for example:

```
if (map.getLayer('points')){
    map.removeLayer('points');
}

if (map.getSource('point')){
    map.removeSource('point');
}
```